# at what interest rate can one double his initial deposit after 3 years, if the interest is compound semiannually? 24.5% 0.245% 112.25% 1.12%

Tags: algebra-precalculus

really need help with this problem. Its a little vague for me. Thanks

at what interest rate can one double his initial deposit after 3 years, if the interest is compound semiannually?

a.24.5% 
b.0.245% 
c.112.25% 
d.1.12%

Comment: Since this is a multiple choice question, and three of the answers are not reasonable, one does not even need to know how to compute the appropriate interesr rate.

Comment: $2S = S(1+\frac{i}{2})^6$ find i Hence the answer is a)

Comment: @AndreNicolas, I find the choices are absurd and does not test the underpinnings

Comment: @satishramanathan: Three of the choices are indeed clearly impossible. But multiple choice tests typically have too many too easy questions in too little time, so it may make sense to have many of them doable in seconds.  But I have no direct experience with math multple choice tests: I have never have given a multiple choice question, and never will.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, I wrote an exam in the past with multiple choice,namely, Chartered Financial Analyst. Sir, they really test the underpinnings and even if you know the answer, there are a lot of traps which you might succumb to.

Comment: @satishramanathan: The "traps" thing is another issue. Somehow the multiple choice format encourages test makers to try to trick students into giving a wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a multiple choice question, and the last three answers are not reasonable, one does not even need to know how to compute the appropriate interest rate. For the interest rate $0.245\%$ is tiny, and $1.12\%$ is also very small. It would take many years at those rates for our money to double. And at $112.25\%$, our money will double in less than $1$ year.

But let us compute exactly. Let the nominal yearly rate be $r$. Then the half-yearly rate is $r/2$. In $6$ half-years, $1$ dollar grows to $2$ dollars, so
$$2=(1+r/2)^6.\tag{1}$$
It follows that $1+r/2=\sqrt[6]{2}$, and therefore $r=2(\sqrt[6]{2}-1)$. Now compute.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [rule of 72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72), which states that the number of compound periods times the per-period interest rate is approximately $72\%$, in order to double the investment.

For this case, there are $6$ compounding periods, so the interest rate per half year is around
$$\frac{72\%}6 = 12\%$$
And the rate per annum is around $24\%$. Good enough for multiple choice.